# Optimise oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have existing sql script need to optimise. How the script written is like this

```
select * from table A 
  Where (A.ID, A.name, A.age) 
in 
  (
    Select B.ID,B.name, B.age 
    from table B 
    where B.ID in 
    ( 
      Select A.ID from table A Where age = ‘30’
     )
   )
```

When I try to run this it takes very Long time and I have no idea why the previous programmer write in this ways please help if there is better ways to rewrite this. Appreciate much thanks!

Comment: Replace the multiple nested SELECT statements with JOINS instead where possible, for a start.

Comment: Please paste desired output atleast.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are `A` and `B` the same tables?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
Select A.* from (select ID, NAME, age from table A WHERE age = 30) A
LEFT JOIN table B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.NAME = B.NAME AND A.age = B.age
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This give me idea how to rewrite it and it work!

Comment: @QWERTTY123 . . . Can you report on any improvement in performance?